# How to press Keyboard ALT + I in Selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, automated-tests

I need to press Alt + I at the same time

```
Actions actions=new Actions(driver);        actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT+"i"))).build().perform();
```

It doesn't work